# Python Azure Databricks order of widgets not alphabetic

Tags: azure-databricks

I am creating a form with three widgets.
Somehow Microsoft Azure Databricks sorts the widgets alphabetically, so that `IP From` comes before `Type`. How can I make `Type` come before `IP From`?

```
# Form
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="inp_type", defaultValue="IP", choices=["IP", "Host"], label="Type:")
dbutils.widgets.text(name="inp_ip_from", defaultValue="none", label="IP From:")
dbutils.widgets.text(name="inp_ip_to", defaultValue="none", label="IP To:")
```

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make `Type` come before `IP From`?

To fix your issue, please `drag and drop` your required widgets in an `order`.

*Below are the steps to fix it in an order.*

1. Click on the `edit` option from ADB Workspace Notebook as shown in below screenshot,

[image]

2. Drag the widgets in `order` you want to place it and click on `save`.

[image]

***Output:***
[image]